# How do I turn off the pop-ups that appear everytime I mouse-over a tag?

Tags: support, tags

Title says it all, I find it incredibly distracting and it's frequently difficult to get them to go away once they've appeared.

Doubt if it's relevant, but I'm using Firefox on Windows.

Comment: Alright, since @iglvzx mentioned [that he might do a blog entry about this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5438160#5438160), let's just move that to MSU then.

Comment: Those things are a long-standing annoyance. They SHOULD collapse once the mouse pointer moves away, but they usually don't.

Comment: I usually have the reverse issue when editing tags on a question and not being able to get this popup :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use Chrome's *Inspector* tools from *Developer » Developer Tools* – or the Firefox equivalent from *Tools » Web Developer » Inspector* – you can try to find out the element's CSS selector and then turn off its visibility altogether:

#### Chrome:

[image]

#### Firefox:

[image]

Therefore, on Super User, following CSS rule will just make them disappear.

```
#tag-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

You can use the Stylish add-on for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) or [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) to define site-specific styles.

Comment: I've heard of the Stylish FF extension before and wondered of what use it might be, so guess it's time to find-out... (I'd prefer not switching broswers).

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! Learning curve was too bad, either. ;-)

Comment: I meant "wasn't too bad" of course. OTOH, seems like a lot of trouble for something that ought to easier to disable (or not be there at all).

Comment: Well, Stack Exchange doesn't like having user configuration, so I guess that's all you can do :)

Comment: If one has the AdblockPlus extension to the browser, one can add the custom filter "superuser.com##div#tag-menu" to the list. Works well in Firefox, not sure about Chrome.

Comment: @kreemoweet: Actually I like your suggestion about using AdBlockPlus a little better because that's an add-on I already use so wouldn't have to have yet-another-ff-extension to do this one little thing. Very clever, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a separate answer, but rather to allow me to elaborate slightly on @slhck's suggestion of using the Stylish Firefox extension for anyone else interested in doing it. After [downloading](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) and installing the add-on, I manually added the following style and named it `NoTagMenu`:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("superuser.com"), domain("stackoverflow.com")  {

/* ccs rule */
#tag-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

As you can see, I have it also applied to the stackoverflow domain, which has the same issue (no surprise).