# Superuser tag never appropriate?

Tags: discussion, tags

[How do I turn off the pop-ups that appear everytime I mouse-over a tag?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5260/how-do-i-turn-off-the-pop-ups-that-appear-everytime-i-mouse-over-a-tag)

The question was migrated but there was no tag cleanup.

https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/superuser

Seems there would never be a reason to use this tag. Candidate for a permanent tag ban?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Migration stubs are deleted after 30 days and once the stub is deleted, the tag will no longer be present on other questions and hence will be auto removed from the system.

Tag blacklists are exceedingly rare, I don't think there's any need to put [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/superuser) under a blacklist for now

Comment: Is there a problem with "superuser" beside it being the name of our site? I think it should be a synonym of "root", if we're keeping that tag.

Comment: @iglvzx there's no problem as such, neither are there any questions using the tag - don't see the need for adding a synonym yet